# UIKit: how can I round and clip the corners of a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar

I would like to round the two bottom corners of my navigation controllers's bar, so it looks like this:

[image]

I tried this:

```
final class RoundedNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    }
}
```

But here is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Why does the safe area part get clipped too?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the safe area part get clipped too?

The bounds top of the navigation is at the *bottom* of the status bar. The *drawing* of the navigation bar is extended upward *beyond* its bounds into the "status bar" area (and on up to the top of the screen).

For this reason, you *cannot* set a navigation bar's `clipsToBounds` to `true`, as you will break the way it draws.

A better strategy might be to construct the navigation bar's background image to look the way you want it. So, for example, I was able to get this effect:

[image]

But *not* by rounding the layer corners and clipping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, does this mean it is impossible to do?

Comment: It's impossible if "it" involves rounding the layer and clipping. You can _draw_ the navigation bar image as you are describing, you just can't clip. I've added a screenshot to show you.